# When will the API functionalities of MS graph beta version be available in the V1 version?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to know when the the APIs currently available in the beta preview version be available in the v1 version of MS graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** overarching date for everything in beta to move to v1.

As functionality matures, it gets moved over from beta to v1. For example, in May 2016, *extensions* were graduated from beta to v1 for Messages, Contacts and Events.

Likewise, as new functionality is made available for preview, it is exposed via the beta endpoint, as was the case June 2016 with IdentityRiskEvents.

You can keep track of what gets introduce to beta and what gets graduated to v1 in the [Microsoft Graph Change Log](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/changelog).

If there's something in particular you'd like to see graduated to v1, please shared your feedback via the [Microsoft Graph UserVoice Forum](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).